# Why Can I Not Implement @font-face?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

My problem is that custom fonts do not display when using `@font-face`.

My CSS is referenced in it's own file and the code is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MerceariaAntique';
    src: url('type/mercearia_new/21319b_0_0-mercearia.eot');
    src: url('type/mercearia_new/21319b_0_0-mercearia.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-    opentype'),
         url('type/mercearia_new/21319b_0_0-mercearia.woff') format('woff'),
         url('type/mercearia_new/21319b_0_0-mercearia.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('type/mercearia_new/21319b_0_0-mercearia.svg#webfontuploaded_file')     format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }
```

In my HTML file I have referenced it as the following alongside the main CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/fonts.css" />
```

I suspect I have referenced it incorrectly, but I can't find out how to reference it correctly.

Comment: A link to live demo would be helpful.

Comment: I agree. Your code looks good, a live example might help us pinpoint where the problem exists.

Comment: Ok, if I don't solve the issue later on tonight I will post up a live example. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what is your folder structure?? 
if you calling css inside a folder "css" you must point out the correct path to custom fonts
like this "../"

```
src: url('../type/mercearia_new/21319b_0_0-mercearia.eot');
```

Comment: This is something I can't try as I have just left the computer, but they are not referenced like your example (as you can see)

Comment: put your fonts in in root directory inside `"type"` --> `"mercearia_new"` folder and check

Comment: This is the correct answer - I had failed implement the very simple "../" part of the url.  Thanks Hareesh!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use @font-face:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Example Font";
  src: url("http://www.example.com/fonts/example");
}
h1 {
  font-family: "Example Font",  sans-serif;
}
```

I assume you have already checked e paths of the font files and they are correct.
I also assume you have checked your Error Console for any CSS warnings or errors like file not found.

Try double checking where you are assigning the font as a `font-family` in your code.

Also, a `font-face` reference: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/at-fontface

**UPDATE:** Try [WebFont Loader](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader#Example) from Google

Comment: I don't see how that doesn't comply with his example.

Comment: I did not say it did not comply, but I did include a assignation to h1. You omitted that from your question. It might be helpful. Are the font file links in the @font-face definition correct? Try referencing them with the URL included like this: http://domain.com/css/font.css rather than just css/font.css

Comment: Sorry yes I did omit that. However, I'm calling the font correctly as I can display the font if I use it's local name. As soon as I try to call using the font face name then it breaks. I have also tried a full URL with no success.

Comment: Try WebFont Loader. I included a link in my answer.