# Browser is not displaying the correct font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have this code in my CSS file, but the browser doesn't display the font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font';
    src: url("fonts/FS_Metal.ttf");
}

.menu_head {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: 'font';
}
```

Comment: Try: `font-family: font`

Comment: i've tried ie , chrome and firefox , the same problem

Comment: Best guess: duplicate of [Why Can I Not Implement @font-face?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307270/why-can-i-not-implement-font-face)

Comment: @Mr_Green it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Are you sure that the "fonts" directory is at the same level of the CSS file?

Comment: add the directory structure you have to your question.

Comment: I don't know what's your directory structure but I think you should try `src(../fonts/FS_Metal.ttf)`

Comment: the css file level is the same of fonts folder , i'm sure the problem is not from the directory

Answer (score 4):

this should be crossbrowser

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'your_font';
    src: url('../font/your_font.eot');
    src: url('../font/your_font.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../font/your_font.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../font/your_font.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../font/your_font.svg#your_font') format('svg');
}

.menu_head {font-family:'your_font',serif;}
```

I am using http://convertfonts.com/ ... it will do all work for you

also check if path to your font files is correct

Answer (score 2):

This is due to `src: url("fonts/FS_Metal.ttf");` this line. You need to make sure the relative path is correct. Alternatively you can use an absolute path.

Say your directory structure is as follows:

Directory Structure:

```
index.html
css/
js/
fonts/
```

#### using relative path do the following in your css file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font';
    src: url("../fonts/FS_Metal.ttf");
}
```

#### using absolute path do this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font';
    src: url("http://yoursite.com/fonts/FS_Metal.ttf");
}
```

I would also recommend you to look at [Google Webfonts API](http://www.google.com/webfonts)

Comment: this is the correct directories

index.html
cssfile.css
fonts/