# firefox is not viewing the font while ie and chrome are viewing it correctly

Tags: html, css, fonts

firefox is not viewing the font while ie and chrome are viewing it correctly

this is the CSS code:

```
.menu_head {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: fs_metal;
}
```

Comment: have you included all the font formats like .eot, .ttf, .woff etc.

Comment: no , i don't have them all , only .ttf

Comment: i have only .ttf type

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15613825/1611349

Comment: Not enough information. Check old questions about `@font-face` (this must be about it, even though it is not mentioned in the question) and post relevant info such as URL of online version and origin of font, if problems remain.

Answer (score 0):

Are yo using @font-face to import a font? Becuase if you are firefox has a very specific way of dealing with this.

Here is another post on SO detailing this

[CSS @font-face not working with Firefox, but working with Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15218631/2062450

Comment: Hosted on the site? Look at the second answer X

Comment: hmm ok, have you tried the @font-face generator of http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: Maybe try downloading it again and then using the new file?